# Codeigniter with Pdo issue call to a member function rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, codeigniter-2

I have used codeigniter 2.2.0 and want to use pdo db connection with pdo driver but getting error something like this so can anyone figureout what i am missing here?

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['dsn'] = '';
$db['default']['hostname'] =    'mysql:host=192.168.1.222;dbname=test';
$db['default']['username'] = 'admin';
$db['default']['password'] = 'admin';  
$db['default']['database'] = 'test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

after this when i run the project i getting this fatal error occured 
**Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/collegelife/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_result.php on line 42**

Comment: which code please describe @saty?

Comment: Check https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3095

Comment: i am not using rowCount in query its in pdo_result.php which is codeignitor default file comes with framework

Comment: Yaa check above link

Comment: @Darshanambaliya use MySQLi. Its best than using  PDO

Comment: @saty i check that link but i already riffer that link and change the code for that part but doesn't work.thanks for your time

Comment: @abdulla is that mysqli is not depreciated right??

Comment: @Darshanambaliya check answer below

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of PDO. **Reason [Check Sarty's comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719528/codeignitor-with-pdo-issue-call-to-a-member-function-rowcount#comment62911833_37719528)**

> As well Don't use [**mysql**](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php). Its **deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0**

---

**Setting up MySQLi**

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array()
);
```

Comment: "Use Mysqli instead of PDO." --- any rational reason behind this advice?

Comment: @zerkms Yes of course. Check this. **Related to codeigniter** https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3095#issuecomment-45544435

Comment: It explains nothing, sorry. Any technical reasons, not just someone's feelings? Did not he refer to terrible code of CI?

Comment: @zerkms read from the top of the link. Cz  can't setup it in my PC too

Comment: If you are referring to the bad implementation of CI wrapper over PDO you need to mention that explicitly, otherwise it looks like what you mean is that PDO by itself is bad.

Comment: @zerkms ya when you comment me first. I got the point what you expect. Thanks any way

Comment: @zerkms Thanks zerkms for your feedback regarding query if you found any solution with pdo let me know

Comment: @Darshanambaliya check the answer. If its help dont forget to accept it

Comment: @abdulla it works with mysqli but client want to use pdo only because using pdo you can use mysql and anyother database like sqllite,postgrey so thats why i am asking

Comment: @Darshanambaliya if i u use pdo or myslqi no changes in actibe record query. Only its change in database.php file. As well you can use other db drivers. Tht doents have any problem with it

Comment: @ i want to use only pdo it you have solution with pdo then let me know